# Show a single hidden folder in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

How can I reveal an individual hidden folder, as opposed to showing all hidden folders and files? I'm trying to move folders and files around, but I cannot see one of the folders or it's files in finder.

**Description**

I'm migrating posts from WordPress to Jekyll. My exporter created markdown files in a hidden folder, unexpectedly. I am trying to move the markdown files from the hidden folder to a Jekyll site I've previously setup. In Terminal, I have created a copy of the markdown files in the correct directory. However, because the exporter generated folder was hidden, all of the contents have remained hidden. I cannot see the files in Finder and Jekyll cannot render the files correctly when I try to start the server.

**Update 1:** I have created an issue on the github page for the exporter, but I haven't gotten a response yet. I have tried some of the solutions below, including using `Finder> Go to folder...` and `chflags -R nohidden ~/jekyll-site`. Due to the `Go to folder...`, I am now able to see the folders created by the exporter. However, the folders still appear empty in Finder. `chflags` hasn't helped.

**Update 2:** I ran  `ls ~/jekyll-sites/subdir | wc -l`, as suggested below. I got "11". Meanwhile, I thought that if I just started the server that would help. It kind of did: my posts are showing up correctly on the blog, which is an improvement, but I still don't actually see them in Finder. I've tried opening the posts in Sublime and trying a `Save As`. When I do, I can see them all listed in the dialog but they are all greyed out. What's more, I get an alert "A file with this name already exists".

**Update 3**
Tried a solution to create copy of the files, without the "._" prefix in case that could copy the files without copying the problem. That didn't work, but I wanted to include that here in case it's helpful to others.

1. Open Terminal. (Assuming it's opening to your Home Directory in which the jekyll-sites directory is in.)
2. Copy and paste the following command into the Terminal then press Enter: zip -r jekyll-sites.zip jekyll-sites -x "._*"; open jekyll-sites.zip
3. Open Finder and there should now be a jekyll-sites 2 folder in your Home Folder.

**Solution:** No idea why this worked, but I ended up restarting Finder, which seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: Before raising the meta question read what on hold is used for http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions and the unclear what you're asking

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34499/discussion-on-question-by-user70848-show-a-single-hidden-folder-in-finder).

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark workaround however I think it's worth a try.   1. Open Terminal. (Assuming it's opening to your Home Directory in which the `jekyll-sites` directory is in.) 2. Copy and paste the following command into the Terminal then press Enter: `zip -r jekyll-sites.zip jekyll-sites -x "._*"; open jekyll-sites.zip` 3. Open Finder and there should now be a `jekyll-sites 2`  folder in your Home Folder.  Can you see all the files/folders in the `jekyll-sites 2` hierarchal folder structure or are they still invisible?

Comment: @user3439894 What does this do?

Comment: It creates a zip archive file of the contents of the `jekyll-sites` directory recursively while excluding files that start with `._` and whatever the rest of the name is, hence the `*`  and then extracts the zip file which will be the name of the source directly incremented, hence `jekyll-sites 2`.  There can be information in the `._*` files that caused the files to be hidden to Finder and by not including them when archived in the zip file and then the remaining files extracted then hopefully the hierarchal folder structure of `jekyll-sites 2` will be visible.  So try it and see if it works.

Comment: @user3439894 That was pretty cool. Unfortunately, what happened was that it created a completely empty (looking) jekyll-sites-1 folder. I checked in Terminal and everything is in there, it's just not showing up. : /

Comment: Eureka! I found the answer: I quit Finder and restarted. I see everything now, even your new jekyll-sites folders. @user3439894 thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `chflags` in a Terminal to hide/unhide a *file* where *file* is an individual *file* or *folder* or when using the `-R` *option*, all *files/folders* within a *folder*.  See: `man chflags`

Basic syntax to hide a *file* is:

```
chflags hidden file
```

Or *folder* and everything in it:

```
chflags -R hidden file
```

Basic syntax to unhide a *file* is:

```
chflags nohidden file
```

Or *folder* and everything in it:

```
chflags -R nohidden file
```

Note: If the folder is a system folder you'll need to preface the `chflags` command with `sudo`, e.g.: `sudo chflags nohidden file`

Also with OS X 10.11 SIP may have to be disabled, although not sure on that as I'm not running OS X 10.11 and cannot test.

Comment: This is what I get: > chflags nohidden file
chflags: file: No such file or directory

Comment: @user70848, Did you read the man page for `chflags`?

Comment: I don't know what 'See: man chflags' means.

Comment: In a Terminal you type `man chflags` and press Enter, then read.  In the examples given _file_ is a placeholder and represents the actual name of the _file/folder_ to be unhidden/hidden that you'll type in.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but I still get empty folders. :/

Answer (score 4):

For just moving files and folders within the hidden folder, it might actually not even be necessary to unhide the folder as long as you know its name—or know how to get it.

For example: I know that a `Library` folder exists within my user folder but I cannot see it in the Finder:

[image: Screenshot of user home directory]

However, I can use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to open a prompt where I can type in a folder I want to go to.
If that shortcut doesn’t work for you, in Finder’s toolbar select `Go > Go to Folder`. The input field there actually has tab completion like the terminal does with bash, so you can, e.g., type in `~/Lib`, press <kbd>tab</kbd> and it will automatically be turned into `~/Library/`.

[image: Screenshot of Go To Folder prompt]

This, as I mentioned earlier, only works if you know where to find the hidden folder.
If you don’t, you can open the Terminal (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, type `Terminal`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd>) and get to the closest folder where you think the hidden folder might be and then type `ls -al`. This lists all files—including hidden ones—as a detailled list. Hidden files usually start with `.`.

Once you got the exact path, you can try what I wrote above with the Finder’s `Go to folder` action.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an empty Finder list.

Comment: Actually, I'll say that the folders now show up - although Finder says they can't be found - but they are empty.